# attached comments loop too many times javascript

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I've been having an error where I can't properly attach my comments to the message id. below is what I have tried.

routes file:

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res){
    if(req.cookies.user_id){
        knex.raw(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${req.cookies.user_id}`)
            .then(function(user){
                knex.raw(`SELECT * FROM messages JOIN users on users.id = 
                messages.user_id`)
                .then((joinInfo)=>{
                   knex.raw(`SELECT comments.id, users.username, messages.id 
                   as mess_id, messages.body, comments.message_id, users.id 
                   as us_id, comments.commentsbody, comments.created_at, 
                   comments.updated_at FROM comments JOIN messages ON 
                   comments.message_id = messages.id JOIN users on 
                   comments.user_id = users.id`)
                  .then((commentInfo)=>{
                  res.render('loggedInHome', {user: user.rows[0], 
                 messagedata: joinInfo.rows, title: 'Seddit', commentInfo: 
                 commentInfo.rows})
               })
          });
      }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log(err, 'ERRRRR')
          res.redirect('/')
    })
 }
```

})

ejs views page

```
      <main class='main_content'>
        <% for (var j = 0; j < messagedata.length; j++) { %>
        <div class='message_box'>
            <p><strong><%= messagedata[j].username %></strong>: <%= 
            messagedata[j].body %></p>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < commentInfo.length; i++) { %>
            <% if (commentInfo.mess_id == messagedata.comment_id) { %>
                 <p><strong><%= commentInfo[i].username %> 
                 comments</strong>: <%= commentInfo[i].commentsbody %></p>
            <% } %>
       <% } %>
       <% } %>
       </div>
     </main>
```

On localhost when I view the info. It is looping too many times and when I console.log the if statement it usually responds with undefined.

Comment: Where exactly is the issue? What is being spit out in the console, what does the structure of the returned data look like?

Comment: `console.log the if statement it usually responds with undefined` - show what / where you console log

Comment: its pretty much like a clone of reddit so a user can create a message. the issue I'm having is that when I am trying to show the comments attached to that message the comments pop up but they are not attached to their specific message.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because that you are putting one for loop within another, so the inner loop would show the result times the number of your outer loop runs.